# Java Null Pointer Exception on 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()'

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I was trying to add a collapsing Toolbar to a Fragment, but the app crashed as soon as I opened the Fragment:
This is the error I get:

```
2018-10-19 18:05:38.950 13301-13301/io.github.davidwickerhf.diceroller E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: io.github.davidwickerhf.diceroller, PID: 13301
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
    at io.github.davidwickerhf.diceroller.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:36)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:809)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7436)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
```

Fragment Java:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private MainActivity mMainActivity;
    private SettingsViewModel settingsViewModel;
    private SettingAdapter adapter;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private View fragmentView;

    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        mMainActivity = new MainActivity();

        androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar mToolbar = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.profile_toolbar);
        mMainActivity.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(mMainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.AddFragment(new ProfileInfoFragment(), "Profile");
        adapter.AddFragment(new ProfileMessagingFragment(), "Messages");
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_profile);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        return fragmentView;
    }
}
```

The Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".ProfileFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:toolbarId="@id/profile_toolbar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background_image_Toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/profile_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout_profile"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/greyText"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/greyText"
        android:background="#fafafa"
        android:elevation="0dp">

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>





<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">













    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

Please help?

Comment: Try to replace this "mMainActivity = new MainActivity();" for this: "mMainActivity = getActivity()" just for tests

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried your suggestion, but the code doesn't compile because with the function getActivity() I return the fragment

Comment: You can do this: mMainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

Comment: @W0rmH0le Thank you very much! It worked!

Comment: Nice. I'll post as an answer then.. for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are getting that error because you are instantiating a new `MainActivity` object:

```
 mMainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

In case of `Fragments`, you can call `getActivity()` to get the reference of the activity that is hosting your `Fragment`. Something like:

```
private MainActivity mMainActivity;
....
mMainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```

Or, you don't even need to cast to `MainActivity` since you are invoking a common method (available on `Activity`)

```
private Activity mMainActivity;
....
mMainActivity = getActivity();
```